# USB FastE or GigE that "just works" with Linux 2.6 kernels

Tags: networking, ethernet, debian

I am trying to find a USB FastEthernet or GigabitEthernet that works without recompiling Debian Squeeze or Ubuntu Oneric.

So far, I have tried the following USB GigE adapters:

- Belkin F4U047-RS
- Sabrent USB-NT20
- Linksys USB300M
- Apple MC704ZM/A

When I inserted them in a Debian Squeeze machine, all of them would show up as an interface in `dmesg`; however, I could never get them to actually link up with an ethernet switch. I was using a cable that was known-good, and I was using an ethernet port that worked with the on-board GigE jack.

I know I can [recompile and get the Linksys USB300M working](http://ubuntuforums.com/showthread.php?t=1480230); however, I have to get interfaces up quickly for any random linux server in our lab (which are mostly Debian / Ubuntu).

Throughput is really a low priority for these, the need is mostly just basic network connectivity when I fire up a new motherboard, and the on-board GigE isn't recognised for whatever reason; other times, I may need a spare interface for a quick firewalling project.

Comment: If throughput is a low priority, will a Fast Ethernet (100 Mbps) adapter do instead?

Comment: FastEth is acceptable as long as it is still commercially available today; however, I prefer GigE since there is a better chance of being able to buy it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast Ethernet USB adapters are widely available and should be for a couple of years at least. For example, [the majority of USB network adapters at Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100010064%20600016288&IsNodeId=1&name=USB) are still Fast Ethernet :-)

Among those, I would highly recommend the [D-Link DUB-E100](http://dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/support/product/dub-e100-high-speed-usb-2-fast-ethernet-adapter) as something I have personally used and that works out-of-the-box; it has in-kernel drivers. I see that it now comes in two revisions, A and B, but the internal chipset should be identical.

From the official [Linux-USB page](http://www.linux-usb.org/devices.html), the module is `usbnet` and the supported chipset is the ASIX AX88172. Alternative adapters mentioned there include the Hawking UF200 and Netgear FA120.

Comment: By far, DUB-E100 is the easiest to find... many thanks! Apologies for the delay in accepting.