# Ultrabook convertibles that work fully with Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, tablet, ultrabook

Are there any ultrabook convertible laptops that work fully with Ubuntu or can easily be made to fully work?  I would like a device like the Lenovo Yoga and the Dell XPS convertible that works fully or has been known to do so.

Answer (score 3):

**You can** get Ubuntu up and going on the Yoga [Lenovo 20175]. The problem is net access. Wifi doesn't work and no built-in RJ-45 (basic Ethernet jack). Need a USB to RJ-45 that will work with Ubuntu.

I used the Belkin F4U047. Which would overheat on Ubuntu (not Win8) and stop working off and on.

[USB FastE or GigE that "just works" with Linux 2.6 kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169822/usb-gige-that-just-works-with-linux-2-6-kernels)

**Installing** was pretty easy though. Turn off the comp, plug in your Ubuntu USB installer. Push the small button next to the power button in front with a pen/paperclip, choose to boot from USB. Then Install.

**Touchscreen** worked great. Seemed better than Win8. Especially with closing windows etc. with small areas. Pinching to zoom didn't work.

**Multi-touch touch pad** didn't seem to work. ex. 2 finger scroll. *Scroll on right side of pad worked.* Pinching, swiping from the the sides or top/bottom didn't do anything.

**Display flipping** didn't work at all. Fold into tablet mode, turn display upside down, this way that way, shake shake, nothing. Keyboard and touch pad should deactivate... nope.

**Bluetooth** can be turned on. But still showed disabled on setting window.???

Sure felt like being home after Win8 for a few months and glad to see it works as well as it does. Viva la Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Can those problems be solved with future driver updates?  I would love for the Yoga to work with Ubuntu and GNOME Shell.

Comment: Surprised it worked this well, last year, considering Lenovo said there are no Ubuntu touch drivers. Can you update this answer for latest 13.04?